# Why does RegOpenKeyEx return "0" value?

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks, registrykey

I use CodeBlocks version 20.03 (x86) as IDE.

Here are my codes:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "windows.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HKEY hkRegedit;
    long longHataKodu;

    longHataKodu = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\Microsoft\\Chkdsk", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hkRegedit);

    cout << longHataKodu;

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

But the problem is even I run my program without administrator privileges, my program returns `0`.

Here is the screenshot of my program:

[image]

How is that possible even I have written `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and `KEY_ALL_ACCESS`?

As far as I know, value `0` means `ERROR_SUCCESS`.

Comment: That's what `RegOpenKeyEx` returns when it's successful.  What else do you expect it to return?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-virtualization

Comment: And `ERROR_SUCCESS` is 0.

Comment: @molbdnilo It is not possible to access HKLM with KEY_ALL_ACCESS if you do not run the program with administrator privileges. So, I think there is a bug related Codeblocks or MinGW compiler.

Comment: @ÇAĞATAYKAYA It is absolutely 100% certain that the problem is not with the IDE or the compiler, and it is possible in some cases. Did you check the details in that virtualization article?

Comment: @molbdnilo Then REG_KEY_DONT_VIRTUALIZE flag should fix my problem. The error code should be 5 which means "Access denied."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Registry virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-virtualization) is a compatibility shim for old applications that redirects writes to `HKEY_USERS\<User SID>_Classes\VirtualStore` instead of causing access denied errors.

To turn it off, add a [manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests) to your application with a `requestedExecutionLevel` node to mark yourself Vista/UAC compatible.

Comment: Adding a manifest to my application has been fixed my problem. And I think there is a little good in all evil. In this way I have learnt what "Registry Virtualization" is. I did not even know this technology until I encountered this error. Now my application throws "Access is denied." error (Error Code: 5).